# Sending reply message from python script

Tags: python, activemq-classic

I developed a camel application that has capabilities to communicating to external systems via Active MQ broker and at the moment I am putting together a short presentation to show how it works.

For that I chose python as the external system as it is free, easy to install and had a bit of exposure in the past with some jython scripts.
What I want to show in my presentation is that  whenever my system sends a message to the external client via a certain queue, that client will get it do some processing and reply back to the “reply-to” queue as specified in the message header.

So I changed a bit one of the python example scripts which come with Active MQ distribution. Here there is my modified script:

```
import time
import sys
import os
import stomp

user = os.getenv("ACTIVEMQ_USER") or "admin"
password = os.getenv("ACTIVEMQ_PASSWORD") or "password"
host = os.getenv("ACTIVEMQ_HOST") or "localhost"
port = os.getenv("ACTIVEMQ_PORT") or 61613
destination = sys.argv[1]

class MyListener(stomp.ConnectionListener):

  def __init__(self, receiver, sender):
    self.receiver = receiver
    self.sender = sender
    self.count = 0
    self.start = time.time()

  def on_error(self, headers, message):
    print('received an error %s' % message)

  def on_message(self, headers, message):
    if message == "SHUTDOWN":

      diff = time.time() - self.start
      print("Received %s in %f seconds" % (self.count, diff))
      self.receiver.disconnect()
      self.sender.disconnect()
      sys.exit(0)

    else:
      if self.count==0:
        self.start = time.time()

      self.count += 1
      if self.count % 1000 == 0:
         print("Received %s messages." % self.count)

      if 'reply-to' in headers:
        replyTo = headers['reply-to']
        response = '%s Python says: this is very good indeed' % self.count
        self.sender.send(response, destination=replyTo, persistent='false')

sender = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports = [(host, port)])
sender.start()
sender.connect(login=user, passcode=password)

receiver = stomp.Connection(host_and_ports = [(host, port)])
receiver.set_listener('', MyListener(receiver, sender))
receiver.start()
receiver.connect(login=user, passcode=password)
receiver.subscribe(destination=destination, id=1, ack='auto')

print("Waiting for messages...")
while 1: 
  time.sleep(10)
```

Then from inside my system I send out ten thousand messages.
If I comment out the sender part I can see in the console output that the python client receives all my messages. However as soon as I am trying to respond back Ia m getting this error message:

```
TypeError: send() got multiple values for argument 'destination'
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the full stack trace I am getting

```
Waiting for messages...
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Dev\python\lib\threading.py", line 920, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\Dev\python\lib\threading.py", line 868, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\Dev\python\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 317, in __receiver_loop
    self.process_frame(f, frame)
  File "D:\Dev\python\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 166, in process_frame
    self.notify(frame_type, f.headers, f.body)
  File "D:\Dev\python\lib\site-packages\stomp\transport.py", line 227, in notify
    rtn = notify_func(headers, body)
  File "D:/work/cls-message-router/gradle/scripts/listener4.py", line 42, in on_message
    self.sender.send(response, destination=replyTo, persistent='false')
TypeError: send() got multiple values for argument 'destination'
```

Can you please spot out what I am doing wrong here and how should I fix it.
My python knowledge is really very limited so a bit of explanations would be very welcome.

Thank you in advance for your inputs.

Comment: Please add the full error traceback to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was on this line:

```
self.sender.send(response, destination=replyTo, persistent='false')
```

Once I added `body=response` all worked perfectly. So the fixed `send` call  looks like this:

```
self.sender.send(body=response, destination=replyTo, persistent='false')
```